# cannot use selenium to click the button on the chrome page by python

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use selenium library in python to open a chrome page and click the "Sign In" button and sign in the input, here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/") 
driver.maximize_window() 
time.sleep(8) 
button = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Sign In").click()
button.click()
```

now it can open the page and maximise the window, but it just closes the page after 8sec, and no error message is given.

Can you please help me to click the button and sign in? Many Thanks!

### Update:

here is the part that I tried to login on the website: from

```
 selenium.webdriver.common.by import By from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.get("https://www.seekingalpha.com/login")
 username = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
 EC.element_to_be_clickable(driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "email")))

 username.send_keys(ACCOUNT)
```

the result is same as the button click. the page is opened and closed.

Answer (score 1):

**This is the simple way to click sing in button**

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)   
driver.get('https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/')
driver.implicitly_wait(time_to_wait=10)
driver.find_element('css selector','.header-main__signup.login-modal- btn').click()
# Your code here
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. I found that the problem is I didn't capture the element correctly, I have already resolved it, but still really thanks your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can wait until you find the element..

Sample code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                ((By.LINK_TEXT, "Sign In")))  # I prefer using XPATH
button.click()

# rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by updating this code:

```
button = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Sign In").click()
```

into this:

```
button = driver.find_element("link text", "Sign In").click()
```

hope it can help you if you meet the same problem. Thanks!